# Advanced list sorting with lambda

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I've got a list of strings, where each string contains a datestring in the second part, e.g.:

```
alist = ['foo_20150901', 'bar_20150801', 'baz_20150701']
```

Now I want to have them ordered ascending with respect to the date. I thought this would work like this:

```
slist = alist.sort(key =(lambda k: int(k.split('_')[-1])))
```

However, printing slist yields `None`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Look up the documentation for `sort`, it ***explicitly*** states ***IN PLACE*** and returning `None`:

```
Docstring: L.sort(key=None, reverse=False) -> None -- stable sort *IN PLACE*
Type:      method_descriptor
```

To return the sorted list you need to use `sorted` instead:

```
In [5]: sorted??
Docstring:
Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

A custom key function can be supplied to customise the sort order, and the
reverse flag can be set to request the result in descending order.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 1):

`L.sort()` sorts the list in-place returning `None`, you want the `sorted` function:

> sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)
>     Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

```
slist = sorted(alist, key=lambda k: int(k.split('_')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alist = ['foo_20150901', 'bar_20150801', 'baz_20150701']
alist.sort(key =(lambda k: int(k.split('_')[-1])))
print alist
```

Output:

```
['baz_20150701', 'bar_20150801', 'foo_20150901']
```